# What projection is my data?

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I received a dataset containing some "XY" coordinates that are **supposed** to correspond to some locations in natural reserves/national parks in Costa Rica. I'm trying to use the `proj4` package in R to try to convert these coordinates to lat/long (using the `project(..., inverse = TRUE)` command), but I cannot figure out which projection was used to get the XY coordinates, so I cannot invert the projection to get the lat/long.

## How can I guess which projection/coordinate system was used?

A few points:

```
  X,       Y
193087, 1056379
193587, 1056917
211524, 1032512
213201, 1032612
```

Comment: Guessing is a *really* bad idea, go back to the person/agency you obtained the data from and *ask* what CRS the data is in.. did you get metadata also? the answer could be there. It does look like undelimited DMS or decimal seconds (is 19.3,105.63 in Costa Rica?) but to *what datum?* Also it looks like the X and Y are swapped. It's much better to ask and know for sure than guess and find out you were wrong invalidating your whole process.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to http://projfinder.com/ , I think I managed to pin it down as EPSG:32617, which has a proj4 string of `+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs` .

That website is actually very helpful, basically you input your mystery XY coordinate and point on a map where you *think* that point is supposed to correspond, and the website spits out a list of projections that seem to match well.

### Of course, the `best` course of action is to `ask the person who created the data` for the correct coordinate system. But if that proves impractical for one reason or another, this is a pretty good backup option.

Comment: Only when you've exhausted *all* avenues of knowing *for sure* the CRS of a dataset should you consider an *educated guess* of the kind offered by this site... if you are forced to guess or assume a CRS be sure to specify in any report you make and if possible include in the files' metadata that the CRS is assumed.

Comment: That's a pretty old system, anything modern will probably be based on the WGS84 ellipsoid as used by GPS, and that is EPSG:32617 which is about 50 metres away from EPSG:26717.

Comment: @Spacedman good call. I switched to that one and it is giving similarly reasonable results

Comment: @MichaelStimson that's definitely the best practice. I've reached out to the person who gave me the data, but I wanted to try to work with the data at least a little bit, while I wait for a response.

Comment: That puts a totally different light on the question, if you're just after something *reasonable* to experiment with while awaiting the *correct* information I suggest that should have been stated in your question... to avoid multiple downvotes.

Comment: @Spacedman you're the winner, that was the right projection according to my data's creator  (UTM 17N on WGS84)